# Lattice: Join of orthogonal elements is set union?

Tags: lattice-theory

I am studying a lattice of closed sets generated by an orthogonality relation $\perp$ with set inclusion as ordering relation and meet and join defined as $(A \land B)=A \cap B$ and $(A \lor B) = (A \cup B)^{\perp\perp}$.

I am now observing that for every two elements A,B with $A\perp B$ the join of A and B is their set union:

$A \lor B = A \cup B$ for every A,B with $A\perp B$

In my special case this seems rather obvious and I was wondering, whether this could be a general feature of orthocomplemented lattices. However I can't find anthing relating to that in the literature.

Could anyone help me with this and maybe point me towards any literature regarding that or maybe just give a counterexample in case it is not a general feature as I am assuming?

Many thanks,

Tobias

Comment: Taking the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocomplemented_lattice), I feel you man be confused about $\cup$ and $\vee$.  At any rate, without a concrete example it is difficult to know what you're thinking.

Consider for example the linear subspaces of ${\mathbb R}^2$ *qua* inner product space. Let $A$ be any one dimensional subspace and $B=A^\perp$ its dual.  Then set-theoretic $A\cup B$ is not a linear subspace but $A\vee B$ is the whole space.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. At which point do you think I could be confused about $\cup$ and $\lor$?
My example is the lattice of closed sets in 2D-Minkowski-Space with orthogonality defined by 

$A\perp B \Leftrightarrow$ there is no timelike curve connecting $a$ with $b$ for every $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

In that case $A\lor B = A \cup B$ holds for every A,B with $A\perp B $. But I think you are right with your example of the linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it's probably a specific property of the lattice I am studying...

Comment: Are your $A$ and $B$ linear subspaces or just subsets? The word "closed" has an awful lot of different meanings in mathematics.

Comment: They are just subsets. in 2D you can imagine them as 'diamonds', for example here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.4345v1.pdf (page 35). In my case you get the closure of a set by applying the orthocomplementation on it two times ($A \leftarrow A^{\perp \perp}$). SO the only conditions on that are, that the orthocomplementation is required to satisfy the complement law, the involution law and the order-reversing as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice

Comment: Sorry, I am not allowed to edit the post once more. Of course it has to be $A \rightarrow A^{\perp \perp}$

Comment: I've thought about it again. My example also doesn't work for $A$ and $A^{\perp}$. But that seems rather obvious to me, since $A \lor A^\perp$ is always the whole set (or space). It would be interesting if my assumption is correct for $B \subset A^\perp$ (excluding $B=A^\perp$).

Comment: I think your confusion arises from allowing $A$ and $B$ to be *arbitrary* subsets, so that $(-)^\perp$ is not an involution ($A=(A^\perp)^\perp$).  In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are single points then $A\cup B$ is of course a doubleton whereas $A\lor B$ is (I think) a diamond or a pair of triangles.

Comment: Well, that's the crucial point. If I choose $A$ and $B$ to be single points (with orthogonality defined like above, i.e. there is no timelike curve connecting $A$ and $B$), then $A=A^{\perp \perp}$ and $B=B^{\perp \perp}$ holds. Now, if $A \perp B$, by $A \lor B$ I get a doubleton and if $\neg(A \perp B)$ I get a diamond...

Comment: Sorry, it's 35 years since Special Relativity was last in my head and you really need to work this out for yourself. I think that $C^\perp$ (in particular $A\vee B$) is always a generalised diamond, ie possibly empty, a singleton, two triangles, a diamond or the whole space, never a doubleton.

Comment: No problem and thanks a lot. I'll think about that...

Comment: So $(\cdot)^{\perp\perp}$ is a closure operation, and you consider the sets closed under that operation? And what does it mean that $A\perp B$?